# Crawl iframe and page at the same time

Tags: python, iframe, scrapy

I just wanted to know if it's possible to crawl a page on a website and extract data from this page and from an iframe in this page at the same time?

I'm using scrapy with python and I already know how to extract data from the iframe...

Thank you for your help!!

---

Thanks to your answer, I made this... But I don't know what to put instead of 'url'... Can  you help me again please?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import re
import numbers
from fnac.items import FnacItem
from urllib.request import urlopen
# from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
# from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Fnac(CrawlSpider): #scrapy.Spider
    name = 'FnacCom'
    allowed_domains = ['fnac.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.fnac.com/MORMANE/srefA5533119-3387-5EC4-82B6-AA61216BF599']

##### To extract links in order to run the spider in them
    # rules = (
    #     Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse'),
    # )

    def parse(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(response.url), "lxml")
        iframexx = soup.find_all('iframe')
        for iframe in iframexx:
            yield scrapy.Request(iframe.attrs['src'],callback=self.parse2)

##### Main function
    def parse1(self, response):
        item1 = FnacItem()

        nb_sales = response.xpath('//table[@summary="données détaillée du vendeur"]/tbody/tr/td/span/text()').extract()
        country = response.xpath('//table[@summary="données détaillée du vendeur"]/tbody/tr/td/text()').extract()

        yield scrapy.Request(url, meta={'item': item1}) #I don't know what to put instead of URL...

    def parse2(self, response):
        same_item = response.meta['item']

        address = response.xpath('//div/p/text()').re(r'.*Adresse \: (.*)\n?.*')
        email = response.xpath('//div/ul/li[contains(text(),"@")]/text()').extract()
        name = response.xpath('//div/p[@class="customer-policy-label"]/text()').re(r'Infos sur la boutique \: ([a-zA-Z0-9]*)')
        phone = response.xpath('//div/p/text()').re(r'.*Tél \: ([\d]*)\n?.*')
        siret = response.xpath('//div/p/text()').re(r'.*Siret \: ([\d]*)\n?.*')
        vat = response.xpath('//div/text()').re(r'.*TVA \: (.*)')

        if (len(name) != 0):
            item['name'] = ''.join(name).strip()
            item['address'] = ''.join(address).strip()
            item['phone'] = ''.join(phone).strip()
            item['email'] = ''.join(email).strip()
            item['nb_sales'] = ''.join(nb_sales).strip()
            item['country'] = ''.join(country).strip()
            item['vat'] = ''.join(vat).strip()
            item['siret'] = ''.join(siret).strip()
            return item
```

Comment: those are two different requests

Comment: And it's impossible to get the data in the same place, even if I make two different requests? Because the data I want aren't all on the iframe

Comment: what do you mean to get the data in the same place? to return an item information from the two different requests?

Comment: Yep exactly, is it possible? Because for now, I have the data from the iframe in a csv file but if it's possible, I want also the data from the page in the same file, ordered by columns, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to combine information from different requests into a similar item, you have to use the `meta` parameter of the requests:

```
def parse1(self, response):
    item1 = {
        ...
    }
    yield Request(url='another_url.com', meta={'item': item1}, callback=self.parse2)

def parse2(self, response):
    same_item = response.meta['item']
    # keep populating the item with the second response
    ...
    yield same_item
```

Comment: Your answer is perfect... I edit my question, could you show me what to do please?

Comment: sorry I can't help you with that, you'll have to check which request needs to be done for getting your information. To check how requests are done you can use `developer tools` on chrome, or firebug on Firefox.

Comment: Ok, no problem, I will find something!! Thanks